# How to force report manually in BigQuery to run?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have wondering if there is an option to run scheduled report in BigQuery manually. I've got report in Google Data Studio that source is BigQuery table which is scheduled from BigQuery view every hour. But sometimes when I am working on query and would like to try if the changes that I have made are correct, but I have to wait that 1 hour to check it out. I read that backfill can do it but if I set start date and end date as today I can't go further. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want realtime reports, just create a View with your query and create a Report in Data Studio that consumes this View.

Another approach would be to put the custom query directly on Data Studio.  This way you can change the query in Data Studio and it will reprocess your data everytime you refresh the report.

Obviously, this is not the most cost-effective or efficient solution, but it is a good workaround if you just want to test something while developing.

For a production scenario (with lots of concurrent users), if you're able to pre-process your data as you already do, your reports will be faster and they'll probably consume less Big Query resources.